# Configure multiple application use common controller model view in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

What is the best way to develop multiple application for common controller, model and view in CakePHP? Does anybody have an idea to develop this type application?

Answer (score 1):

This is what Plugins are for - you can create a set of controllers, models, views (and a lot more), package them together and then deploy them to all of you applications. See [the CakePHP cookbook for specifics](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html).

Using this approach would add an extra plugin portion to your urls, which can be fixed by providing routing rules.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways of doing this.

1. Package your common controllers, models and views as a plugin
2. Put your common code in a separate set of directories and use `App::build()` in bootstrap.php to include those directories:

```
 App::build(array(
      'plugins' => array('/full/path/to/plugins/', '/next/full/path/to/plugins/'),
      'models' =>  array('/full/path/to/models/', '/next/full/path/to/models/'),
      'views' => array('/full/path/to/views/', '/next/full/path/to/views/'),
      'controllers' => array('/full/path/to/controllers/', '/next/full/path/to/controllers/'),
      'datasources' => array('/full/path/to/datasources/', '/next/full/path/to/datasources/'),
      'behaviors' => array('/full/path/to/behaviors/', '/next/full/path/to/behaviors/'),
      'components' => array('/full/path/to/components/', '/next/full/path/to/components/'),
      'helpers' => array('/full/path/to/helpers/', '/next/full/path/to/helpers/'),
      'vendors' => array('/full/path/to/vendors/', '/next/full/path/to/vendors/'),
      'shells' => array('/full/path/to/shells/', '/next/full/path/to/shells/'),
      'locales' => array('/full/path/to/locale/', '/next/full/path/to/locale/')
  ));
```

Comment: thanks but App::build not available in cakephp 1.2 but i used Configure::write('controllerPaths',$controllerPaths); its working fine